# How do I ask git to clean out and rebuild the entire working tree?

Tags: windows, git, filesystems, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

We have something of an ugly mess that needs cleaning up.

In our codebase, certain developers created directories whose name differed only in case. Normally, such a thing would not be an issue; however we are developing on Windows. This proceeded to confuse git and cause us merge conflicts far down the line.

We have since pushed changes to master getting rid of the duplicate directories in the tree (and encountering some Azure DevOps bugs in the process); now all that remains is a large number of incorrect directory names on users' workstations. Due to the case interactions between git and Windows; these won't get cleaned up by a `git pull`.

How do we actually erase and rebuild the working trees without throwing out the local branch state in `.git`? I need to send out instructions so everybody on the team can clean this mess up and those wrong-case local directories don't magically reappear in future commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all files and then do a `git reset --hard`.

```
git rm -r .
# might need an additional rm outside of git if there are directories left over there
# wait 30 seconds or Windows will restore the wrong case
git reset --hard
```

Just be careful not to have any uncommitted changes hanging around.

Comment: ... and stop using windows sounds like a nice second tip :-D

Comment: Our customers want the product to run on Windows so that's that. We could make the jump in weeks. Our customers, not so fast.

Comment: @Joshua About the 30-second wait, can you elaborate on that? (not complaining... just want to learn).

Comment: Windows keeps track of recently deleted files and if you recreate it with a different case it will put the old case back along with some other file attributes. The timeout is about 30 seconds before it considers it a brand new file.

Comment: I had assumed it would be something like that but wanted to get it from someone with knowledge instead of me guessing. Thanks!